# Sending sms programmatically code Problem

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I am writing code to send sms programatically
Program crashes at second last line.

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.messageComposeDelegate = self;
picker.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"123456789"];   // your recipient number or self for testing

picker.body = @"test from OS4";
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
```

Comment: are you trying to present it from a view controller? you can only presentModalViewController from a uiviewcontroller (or subclass of one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume it's safe to say that it implements

```
UIViewController <MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

In which case, I would recommend going back to http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2010/04/mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller-sample.html, copying their example and progressing from there.

Comment: Thanks KevinDTimm , i am using the same example :(

Comment: and with their example, you get that failure?  Is it failing in the emulator or on the device?

Comment: Emulator :( , i havent checked it on device yet

Comment: Did you find a solution? I see you selected this an 'the' answer - what was the resolution?

Comment: You cannot use the SMS-Function in the simulator!